# Ecto: how to define variable default field values in schema?

Tags: elixir

In Ecto, you can give [fields in your Schema](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/1.1.7/Ecto.Schema.html) a default value by specifying them like `field :name, default: "john"`. In the docs, it is stated that this default is stored at compile-time, and that things like `Date.now` or `UUID.generate` do not work.

My question is: How do we create these variable defaults? 
One could say 'just set the value after creating the struct'. However, when working with virtual fields, this is *not* possible. When you use e. g. `Repo.all(MyModel)` or any other querying-commands, virtual fields are set to their default fixed value.

How can we create variable schema field defaults?

Comment: I am not sure I understood the question but you can remove the default value at all and just set it for all records after you've retrieved them with `Repo.all` or if you want to keep the default value, then just rewrite it after retrieval.

Comment: @JustMichael if you do that,  you tightly couple your code: Either all places that use the model need to know about the defaults, or the model needs to know about the ways it is queried from the database.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible. Ecto simply defines a struct and Elixir structs are expanded at compile time.

You can get around this by explicitly having a function to produce the struct with default values or do this in the changeset function via `put_change` and similar.